# php Warning : Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php

I get this PHP warning while installing Omeka Library CMS. How do I fix this ?

> Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear//home/stmikti4/public_html/elib/install/../application/libraries/Omeka/Application/Resource/Layout.php)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/home/stmikti4:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp)
>   in
>   /home/stmikti4/public_html/elib/application/libraries/Zend/Loader.php
>   on line 186

Comment: It is not an error. It is a "Warning"

Comment: so I can ignore it ?? or I should fix it ?

Comment: I think it is your permissions in "/home/stmikti4/public_html/elib/application", check if all users has access to that folder and all subfolders. What is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

To understand what causes this problem you have to look at the Zend_Loader class, at the line 186:

```
public static function isReadable($filename)
{
    if (is_readable($filename)) {  <-- this returns false, should return true.
        // Return early if the filename is readable without needing the
        // include_path
        return true;
    }
    .....
    foreach (self::explodeIncludePath() as $path) {
        .....
        $file = $path . '/' . $filename;
        if (is_readable($file)) {  <-- this here causes your error.
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What happens is this:

1. Zend Loader tries to load "/home/stmikti4/public_html/elib/application/libraries/Omeka/Application/Resource/Layout.php"
2. is_readable($filename) returns false for some reason, please check that. Most probably your file or any of the folders containing it is not readable by Apache user on your system.
3. Next it tries to find the file in your php include paths, one of them is "/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear/".
4. It appends the filename to your include paths and tries to find the file, but your include path is not within your allowed paths and openbase dir restriction is fired, causing your error.

Check if the file exists and Apache user can read it, probably this is causing your issue.